# How to create instance of a generic C# type in F#?

Tags: c#, f#

I would like to write this

```
Bgr<byte>[,] image = new Bgr<byte>[480, 640];
```

C# code in F#. But couldn't figure out how to do so.

Comment: To clarify: There are no "generic C# types". Support for generics is implemented inside the CLR, and C#, F# and VB.NET use the exact same generic types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```ml
let image = Array2D.zeroCreate<Bgr<byte>> 480 640
```

or

```ml
let image : Bgr<byte>[,] = Array2D.zeroCreate 480 640
```

Comment: Oh. I realized I have never worked with 2d arrays, but only jagged arrays. Thank you very much. I will accept it in 7 minutes.